# Текстовые редакторы сильно тормозят

Tags: linux, ubuntu

В чем может быть дело все текстовые gui жестоко тормозят с файлами больше 5mb? gedit открывает файл 3mb где то 30сек или даже минуту, а medit быстрее но там вообще невозможно работать. На win7 тот же нотепад и акепад с куч плагинами все было нормально, стоит limux mint, к примеру открываю файлы с base64

Comment: линух не для гуи.

Comment: @Sergey, ну не знаю те же IDE под линь все открывают мгновенно. Вот в чем дело ?

Comment: уточните: проблема у вас с программой `gedit`?

Comment: с любым gui редактором

Comment: Видимо те которые вы смотрели загружают файлы через read(), а правильные редакторы - через mmap()

Comment: В последнее время (точно не на минтах) gedit прекрасно работает с большими файлами. Даже с кодом (а я его пишу). Походу, пофиксили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gedit, как и многие другие текстовые редакторы, плохо работает с большими файлами.

Я пользуюсь [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), он все открывает.

Comment: да спасибо даж не знал про него. отлично все работает. Но все равно интересно почему те два редактора так дико лагают?